# Model is not bounded in the custom HTML in Razor

Tags: jquery, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Good day fellow developers, I am just learning ASP.NET Core MVC and now I am facing a problem where the model is not bound with the input upon submitting the form. I created the input, specifically a dropdown button through a custom HTML Helper.

I have already tried different solutions, but still the issue persist.

Here is my code:

**BootstrapHtml.cs**

```
public static IHtmlContent BootstrapDropdownFor<TModel, TValue>(
this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list)
{
    var expressionHelper = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;
    var fieldName = expressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var fullBindingName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(fieldName);
    var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullBindingName, "a");
    var metaData = expressionHelper.CreateModelExpression(htmlHelper.ViewData, expression);
    var value = metaData.Model;

    var button = new TagBuilder("input")
                     {  
                         Attributes = 
                             {
                                 { "id", fieldId },
                                 { "name", fullBindingName },
                                 { "type", "button" },
                                 { "data-bs-toggle", dropdown },
                                 { "value", value == null > string.empty : value.ToString() },
                             }
                     }

      var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
      wrapper.AddCssClass("dropdown");
   
      wrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(button);
      button.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(BuildDropdownList(id, list));

      using (var writer = new StringWriter())
      {
          wrapper.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
          string asd = writer.ToString();
          return new HtmlString(asd);
      }
}

private static TagBuilder BuildDropdownList(string id, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems) 
{
    var ul = new TagBuilder("ul")
                 { 
                     Attributes = 
                         {
                             { "class", "dropdown-menu" },
                             { "aria-labelledby", id }
                         }
                 };
    var listItem = new TagBuilder("li");
    listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-item");
 
    foreach(var item in selectListItems)
    {
        var value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.value) ? string.Empty : item.Value;
        var disabledClass = item.Disabled ? "disabled" : string.Empty;
        ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml($"<li value=\"{value}\" class=\"{disabledClass} dropdown-item\">" + $"<span>{item.Text}</span>" + "</li>");
    }
  
    return ul;
}
```

This is how I use the above element in Razor page.

**Test.cshtml**

```
@model SomeModel

<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-url="AreaName/ControllerName/ActionName" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="OnSuccess(data)">

   @Html.BootstrapDropdownFor(a => a.DummyProperty, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ViewDataWithList"])

<button type="Submit">Create Record</button>
</form>
```

Upon clicking the "Create Record" Button I did not see the value selected from the custom HTML. Verified under Developer tool of the browser > Network > FormData (from Payload of the API).
I am assuming the custom HTML was not bounded in the property "DummyProperty" under "SomeModel" model.

Any help/tips/feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: have you checked if the elements are being generated as expected?

Comment: Hi @NevilleNazerane, I think so. From the UI it is displayed as expected. From dev tool, this is the high level source code:

`<div class="dropdown">
   <input data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id ="DummyProperty" name="DummyProperty" > ::after </input>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-item"><span>Text 1</span></li>
  <li class="dropdown-item"><span>Text 2</span></li>
  <li class="dropdown-item"><span>Text 3</span></li>
</ul>
</div>`

Comment: but I did noticed that the created input has an end tag created instead of a self closing tag. Will it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't found any htmlelemnt could  be paresd to formdata when you submit the form

[image]

If you want to keep your design partern without `<select>`,you would need a hidden input and some js/jquery codes  to hold your selected value

For Example,I tried as below:

```
public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static IHtmlContent BootstrapDropdownFor<TModel, TValue>(
this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list)
        {

            var expressionHelper = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;
            var fieldName = expressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var fullBindingName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(fieldName);
            var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullBindingName, "a");
            var metaData = expressionHelper.CreateModelExpression(htmlHelper.ViewData, expression);
            var value = metaData.Model;

            var button = new TagBuilder("input")
            {
                Attributes =
                {
                  {"id", fieldId},
                  {"name", fullBindingName},
                  { "data-bs-toggle", "dropdown" },
                  {"type", "button"},
                  {"value", value == null ? "Select" : value.ToString()},
                  {"class", "myclass"}
                 }
            };
            var hiddeninput = new TagBuilder("input")
            {
                Attributes =
                {
                  {"id", fieldId+"hd"},
                  {"name", fullBindingName},
                  {"type", "text"},
                  {"hidden" ,"true"},
                  {"value","Value" },
                  {"class", "myclasshd"}
                }
            };

            var wrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
            wrapper.AddCssClass("dropdown");
            wrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(button);
            wrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(hiddeninput);
            button.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(BuildDropdownList(fieldId, list));

            using var writer = new StringWriter();

            wrapper.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            string asd = writer.ToString();
            return new HtmlString(asd);

        }

        private static TagBuilder BuildDropdownList(string id, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems)
        {

            var ul = new TagBuilder("ul")
            {
                Attributes =
                {
                 {"class", "dropdown-menu"},
                 {"aria-labelledby", id}
                 }
            };
            var listItem = new TagBuilder("li");
            listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-item");

            foreach (var item in selectListItems)
            {
                var value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value) ? string.Empty : item.Value;
                var disabledClass = item.Disabled ? "disabled" : string.Empty;
                ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml($"<li value=\"{value}\" class=\"{disabledClass} dropdown-item\">" + $"<span>{item.Text}</span>" + "</li>");
            }

            return ul;
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string? SomeProp { get; set; }
       
    }
```

View:

```
@model SomeClass
<form method="POST">

    @Html.BootstrapDropdownFor(a => a.SomeProp, new List<SelectListItem>(){
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Text1",Value="Text1"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Text2",Value="Text2"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Text3",Value="Text3"}
    })

    <button type="Submit">Create Record</button>
</form>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("li.dropdown-item").click(function () {
        var val = $(this).children('span').html()
        console.log(val);
        $(".myclass").val(val)
        $(".myclasshd").val(val)
    })
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Good day Ruikai, thanks for the answer. This solution works on my end. 
By the way, you mentioned earlier that you couldn't found any htmlelement. Is it okay if you could explained this to me? 

Also, I am planning to retain this one as I can't perform any bootstrap styling with the existing `@Html.DropdownListFor`. Because, I was tasked to mimic the select dropdown by Materialize. I added some bootstrap classes but styles won't work. Is there any better way instead of creating a custom HTML helper?